# How do I alternate colors in between Listviews?

Tags: android, listview, background

I am adding simple data into a listview (name and time) and I want to be able to alternate between a white and grey background for each table row. I am currently setting the background color in the xml file.

I am using the code from http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

Thanks

*EDIT*
my code looks like this

```
  //R.layout.custom_list_view is just a list view with grey background
   //(I want it white for every other one)
  //On Create section
  setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            list,
            R.layout.custom_row_view,
            new String[] {"pen","price"},
            new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
            );
    //see function below
    populateList();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = 
    new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 

private void populateList() {
    //for loop would go here
    HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp.put("pen","MONT Blanc");
    temp.put("price", "200.00$");
    list.add(temp);

    HashMap<String,String> temp2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp2.put("pen","Parker");
    temp2.put("price", "400.00$");
    list.add(temp2);
   //theres no place to change the background of my listview
```

Final Edit. Here is an easy solution http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/
Change SimpleAdapter adapter to the custom SpecialAdapter found in the website. Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do implement custom adapter and set background color there:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View convertViews;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertViews = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.startingsquadlistview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            convertViews.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            convertViews = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertViews.getTag();
        }

        if(position % 0) {
            convertView.setBackground(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.col1);
        else
            convertView.setBackground(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.col2);

        return convertViews;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however I do not quite understand what you wrote in your answer. Can you help me tailor it to a listview? Sorry I'm just confused

Comment: @Sean You have to implement custom adapter for it. In your case ArrayAdapter is what you need. The main method of ArrayAdapter is getView(). Here is example of it in my answer. In it you should also set text all texts manually or call super.getView(position, convertView, parent). In this case it will return view that you can use instead of content view. And you can just set background on it

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom list adapter and in there create a global boolean variable called 'alternateColor'. Then in your getView() function put this (in this case 'tv' is your textview):

```
if (alternateColor)
{
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    alternateColor = false;
}
else if (!alternateColor)
{
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    alternateColor = true;
}
```

Click [here](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx) for a tutorial on how to make a custom list adapter.

Comment: The only thing you should do is get color resource throught Resource reference. Direct reference doesn't work properly in such cases

Comment: @Maxim I'm looking at a similar issue right now. Which of these two answers would you recommend as being the better option?

Comment: @jamesw Actually the idea is the same. In one case you set background of item. In another background of textview. It depends on your needs. But remember about geting to color through resources inatance

Comment: Do you need else if, surely just else would do?

Comment: Yeah, just "else" would do.